# how to shape the divider in flutter from sharp to smooth circular on both the corners?

Tags: flutter, dart

Edges are not circular   as expected.

Expectation: to provided UI in below design:

[image: Circular Corner of Divider]

I have wrapped the Dividers with Containers and trying to provide border radius to clipoff the diveder edge.

```
            Container(
              width: 135,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              ),
              child: Divider(
                height: 25
                thickness: 5,
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              ),
            ),
```

Requirement to show IOS ui in Android:

```
position: absolute;
width: 134px;
height: 5px;
left: calc(50% - 134px/2 + 0.5px);
bottom: 8px;

/* #White */

background: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 100px;
```

Comment: A Divider is nothing else than a Container in a Center in a SizedBox (you can check the source code). Just leave out the Divider and shape the Container itself to your liking

Answer (score 2):

You can try to wrap `Divider` in `Container` and then do the clipping things but it would be great if you directly create a `Container` that behaves like `Divider` like this.

You can use this divider widget:

```js
class DividerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DividerWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 10,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Flutter divider can provide me with more customization, which I dont need to add myself. I just need to shape the corners to circular for Divider

Comment: Thanks Cavin. I have done with above. Without using Divider.

Comment: It worked well with customized Container. I am able to use it throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge in Container as shown below .

```
Container(
          width: 135,
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          ),
          child: Divider(
            height: 20,
            thickness: 5,
            color: colorwhite,
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Edges are still not circular I tried Clip.hardEdge